# Translate WolframAlpha query to Mathemtaica code

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

There is a way to convert question from [wolframalpha](/questions/tagged/wolframalpha) to [mathematica](/questions/tagged/mathematica) code?
For example, I asked the question "notable people born in France" on [wolframalpha:http://www.wolframalpha.com/],
 and I want to do the same on [mathematica](/questions/tagged/mathematica) (Version 10).
 Thanks.

Comment: It turns out that it's simply entering "=" at the beginning of [tag:mathematica].

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment above, you can enter "=" at the beginning of a cell and then type your query.

However, you can also get more fine-grained control using `WolframAlpha["your query"]` or `WolframAlpha["your query", format]`.

Further information is available at the following URLs:
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha.html
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WolframAlphaIntegration.html